# Perl 5: namespace issues when `use`ing SWIG-generated module in declared package

Tags: perl, module, namespaces, package, swig

I'm having namespace issues with a Perl module. When I `use` it in a regular script file, all public symbols are imported into the (implicit) `main::` package as expected. But when I try to `use` it in a source file with a package declaration of its own (i.e. typically another module), weird stuff starts to happen.

The module in question can be found on CPAN as [`Ufal::MorphoDiTa`](http://search.cpan.org/~straka/Ufal-MorphoDiTa-v1.3.0.1/lib/Ufal/MorphoDiTa.pod). It is a set of bindings to a C++ library, auto-generated using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). No need to have the lib itself installed to reproduce the test cases below.

First then, a regular script file with no package declaration:

```
# script.pl
use Ufal::MorphoDiTa qw(:all);
use Data::Dumper;

# a closer look at symbols inside the main:: package
my %morph_in_main = %main::{ grep { /morph/i } keys %main:: };
print "main:: namespace:\n", Dumper \%morph_in_main;

# Morpho:: is exported by Ufal::MorphoDiTa
Morpho::load('foo');
```

As expected, the symbols from `Ufal::MorphoDiTa` are imported into `main::` and the `Morpho::load` subroutine gets called (with no visible output, but that's fine):

```
$ perl script.pl
main:: namespace:
$VAR1 = {
          'Morpho::' => *{'Ufal::MorphoDiTa::Morpho::'},
          '_<morphodita/morphodita_perl.cpp' => *{'::_<morphodita/morphodita_perl.cpp'},
          '_</usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Ufal/MorphoDiTa/MorphoDiTa.bundle' => *{'::_</usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Ufal/MorphoDiTa/MorphoDiTa.bundle'}
        };
```

Let's add a package declaration now:

```
# Qux.pm
package Qux;
use Ufal::MorphoDiTa qw(:all);
use Data::Dumper;

# a closer look at symbols inside the main:: package    
my %morph_in_main = %main::{ grep { /morph/i } keys %main:: };
print "main:: namespace:\n", Dumper \%morph_in_main;

# a closer look at symbols inside the Qux:: package    
my %morph_in_qux = %Qux::{ grep { /morph/i } keys %Qux:: };
print "Qux:: namespace:\n", Dumper \%morph_in_qux;

# Morpho:: is exported by Ufal::MorphoDiTa
Morpho::load('foo');
```

As you can see below, in this case, some of the imported symbols wind up in the `main::` package and some in the declared `Qux::` package (perhaps this is intended behavior?):

```
$ perl Qux.pm
main:: namespace:
$VAR1 = {
          '_<morphodita/morphodita_perl.cpp' => *{'::_<morphodita/morphodita_perl.cpp'},
          'Morpho::' => *{'::Morpho::'},
          '_</usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Ufal/MorphoDiTa/MorphoDiTa.bundle' => *{'::_</usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Ufal/MorphoDiTa/MorphoDiTa.bundle'}
        };
Qux:: namespace:
$VAR1 = {
          'Morpho::' => *{'Ufal::MorphoDiTa::Morpho::'}
        };
Undefined subroutine &Morpho::load called at Qux.pm line 11.
```

At any rate, as indicated by the last line of the output, **Perl suddenly can't find the subroutine anymore**. Notice all we really did was add the package declaration before all `use` statements.

Now the cherry on top -- if we `use Ufal::MorphoDiTa` **before** declaring `package Qux`, everything starts working again:

```
# Qux.pm
use Ufal::MorphoDiTa qw(:all);    
package Qux;
use Data::Dumper;
# etc.
```

The output of running the module with `perl Qux.pm` is the same as in the first case, i.e. the sub `Morpho::load` is found, **in spite of** not being prefixed with the `main::` namespace into which it was loaded. Contrast this with the behavior of a standard module like `Data::Dumper` -- when *that* is loaded before the package declaration, the sub `Dumper` has to be referred to as `main::Dumper` when in package `Qux::`.

I'd appreciate any pointers as to what's happening here... It's not that I can't work around it, but the issue is bugging me -- I'm not sure whether it's a quirk of Perl, a bug on the SWIG side of things (I don't have enough Perl-Fu to make sense of the auto-generated bindings module, which has package declarations all over the place), or whether (another plausible alternative) my own ignorance is at fault here. Thanks for any input! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that this is **expected behavior**, as explained pretty succinctly in [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) (emphasis mine):

> Packages may themselves contain package separators, as in $OUTER::INNER::var . This implies nothing about the order of name lookups, however. **There are no relative packages**: all symbols are either local to the current package, or must be fully qualified from the outer package name down. For instance, there is nowhere within package OUTER that $INNER::var refers to $OUTER::INNER::var. INNER refers to a totally separate global package.

Now, the symbols exported by the `Ufal::MorphoDiTa` module all live inside various *subnamespaces* (e.g. the `load` subroutine in the `Morpho::` namespace), so they must always be fully qualified (they are not local to the package into which they're imported). What is potentially confusing is that a `main::` prefix is implicit for symbol lookup, so without a package declaration (i.e. in a regular script), everything works fine, because calling `Morpho::load` is a shortcut for `main::Morpho::load` (and the module was indeed loaded inside `main::`).

But when the module is imported into package `Qux::`, `Morpho::load` must be referred to as `Qux::Morpho::load` because, to paraphrase the perldoc, "there is nowhere within package `Qux` that `Morpho::load` refers to `Qux::Morpho::load`. `Morpho` refers to a totally separate global package [`main::Morpho`]" -- which does not exist, because `Morpho::load` was loaded inside `Qux::`, not inside `main::`.

This explains all of the apparent quirks cited above. A tip of the hat to the good folks over at the [MorphoDiTa project](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/morphodita) for [their help and responsiveness](https://github.com/ufal/morphodita/issues/3) in solving this conundrum!